# php&mysql find parent category name

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have problem about inner join, left join commands.

My category table is:

```
ID  | parent | title
1   | 0      | First Category
2   | 1      | Other Category
```

I have list categorys and I want get parents category title at sql command.

I have tried:

```sql
SELECT cat.ID, cat.title, cat2.title as parentcatname, cat.parent
FROM   categories cat INNER JOIN categories cat2 ON cat2.ID=cat.parent
```

But ıt's not working.

Comment: What's the wrong output

Comment: I cant get parent=0 categorys with this output.

Comment: @saidOnder: You need an *outer* join.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to be able to pull all categories no matter have they parent category or not. `INNER JOIN` filters out all mismatches.

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.parent, p.title parent_title 
  FROM categories c LEFT JOIN categories p 
    ON c.parent = p.id
```

Output:

```
| ID |          TITLE | PARENT |   PARENT_TITLE |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 | First Category |      0 |         (null) |
|  2 | Other Category |      1 | First Category |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10ca3/4)** demo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all parent categories then try query

```
SELECT cat_id FROM categories WHERE parent=0;
```

If you want get parent category of a category

SELECT C.cat_id, P.title FROM categories C LEFT JOIN categories P ON P.parent=C.cat_id;

I haven't tested above code but it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can always debug your SQL by entering it into a validator (loads online), phpMyAdmin's SQL tab or a editor with SQL validation. It looks to me like you have a small typo near your categories table selection.

Always dumb it down if your SQL isn't working. Note that JOINs (inner, left, right, ect) are meant to join TWO or MORE tables.

```
SELECT 
    one.ID, one.title, one.parent, one.title, one.parent, one.title
FROM 
    categories one 
LEFT JOIN 
    categories two
ON 
    one.parent = two.ID
```